# What this regular expression is (re.compile) and when we can use the pattern naming in python?

Tags: python, regex

I have found the following regular expression, and I don't understand what does that mean? I need help to understand that. Specially 'p' in middle of everything:

```
RE_CALLEE = re.compile(r'(?P<callee>\+[0-9]+)')
```

This is an example of code:

`2015-11-01T00:00:17.735616+00:00 x1ee energysrvpol[15690]: INFO consume_processor: user:<<"dbdiayhg">> callee_num:<<"+1288888888">> sid:<<"A1003unjhjhvhgfgvhbghgujhj02">> credits:-0.5000000000000001 result:ok provider:ooioutisrt.ym.ms`

Comment: (?P<name>...)
Similar to regular parentheses, but the substring matched by the group is accessible via the symbolic group name name. Group names must be valid Python identifiers, and each group name must be defined only once within a regular expression. A symbolic group is also a numbered group, just as if the group were not named.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have edited  a little bit my question. I don't understand exactly, when it is written as a named grouping, how can be used later on?@Gábor Erdős

Answer (score 2):

- the `(?P<callee>)` part is a [named capturing group](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#non-capturing-and-named-groups)
- the `\+[0-9]+` would match a plus character followed by one or more digits

Here is how you can get the group by it's name:

```
>>> import re
>>> RE_CALLEE = re.compile(r'(?P<callee>\+[0-9]+)')
>>>
>>> RE_CALLEE.search("test +10").group("callee")
'+10'
```

---

As for your example, how about this pattern:

```
>>> RE_CALLEE = re.compile(r'callee_num:<<"(\+\d+)"')
>>> RE_CALLEE.findall(s)
['+1288888888']
```

Comment: I have seen in the example `(?P<x>abc){3} matches abcabcabc`. The group x matches abc.` .However I don't understand what it means by grouping. For example in above, why doesn't wrote 'x' anywhere?! @alecxe

Comment: @MaryamPashmi naming a group is often just a convenience, you can as well do just `(abc){3}` which is also a saving group, but without a name.

Comment: I understood that x just a name , yes? I mean is not included as a pattern, right? If this is true, I would like to add that, in above example `callee` is used as part of the search expression.@ alecxe

Comment: @MaryamPashmi let's work on some example: provide one with a desired output. Thanks!

Comment: I have added to the question...@ alecxe

Comment: @MaryamPashmi updated the answer, is this what you meant?